# Spring Boot save() not propagating to database

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository

I am trying to test a method that adds an Object to a database through repositories. I have this test:

```
@Test
@Transactional
void testAddTagsToPlannedRecipeOne() {
    int testPlannedRecipeId = 1;

    String[] toAdd = {"YUMSTER", "YUMMEISTER"};

    List<String> toPass = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(toAdd));

    String result = tagService.addTagsToPlannedRecipe(toPass, testPlannedRecipeId);

    System.out.println("count: " + tagRepository.count());

    assertThat(result).contains("Success");

    List<Tag> allInTagRepository = tagRepository.findAll(); // debugging, i see there are 4
    List<TagToPlannedRecipe> allInTagToPlannedRecipeRepository = tagToPlannedRecipeRepository.findAll(); // debugging, i see there are 4

    List<Tag> currentTags = tagService.getTagsForPlannedRecipe(testPlannedRecipeId); // this should have 4 elements now

    assertThat(currentTags).size().isEqualTo(4); // the size is still 2
}


@Transactional
public String addTagsToPlannedRecipe(List<String> newTags, int plannedRecipeId) {
    PlannedRecipes p = plannedRecipesService.getPlannedRecipeById(plannedRecipeId);
    List<Tag> currentTags = getTagsForPlannedRecipe(p.getPlannedRecipeId());

    for (String newString : newTags) {
        Tag t = Tag.builder()
                .tag(newString)
                .build();

        if (!currentTags.contains(t)) {
            tagRepository.saveAndFlush(t);
            TagToPlannedRecipe tagToPlannedRecipe = TagToPlannedRecipe.builder()
                    .tag(t)
                    .plannedRecipes(p)
                    .build();
            tagToPlannedRecipeRepository.saveAndFlush(tagToPlannedRecipe);
        }
    }

    return "Successfully added the tags to the planned recipe!";
}
```

Both repositories, the tagRepository and tagToPlannedRecipeRepository, start with 2 entries (2 Tag objects). The test adds 2 entries into each repository, representing an additional 2 Tag objects.

So when I call getTagsForPlannedRecipe, I expect the returned list of tags to be 4, because I've just added 2 additional Tags to it. However, it is still 2.

When I debug, I see that the 2 tags have been correctly added to each Repository.

What is going on here? Why is the getter not returning the updated version? Sidenote that if I add in a Thread.sleep after adding, and I check the H2 console (the tests use an H2), the database does not show the additional 2 tags (but again, the repositories do).

Comment: I can not see where you are calling `save` in your code.  Also `allInTagRepository` is not a repository it is a `List`

Comment: save() gets called in the addTagsToPlannedRecipe method. I've added it to the post. You're right about the second part, I meant tagRepository (edited the fix)

Comment: so in your database do you have four records with the same id of 1 ?

Comment: That's the thing, when I view the H2 database in the console, I don't see any of my changes propagated. However, if I change my test case to check the repositories themselves (i.e. call findAll() and check if the resulting list contains the 4 records with id 1), it works, and the test passes.

Comment: In your code you are inserting into `tagRepository` - I have no idea what `tagService` is, but this is what you are saying does not have 4 records.

Comment: What does getTagsForPlannedRecipe do?